# Calulating free area in CFrame

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dock

I have 4 CToolbars in MyCFrame. They are docked on MyCFrame. How can I calculate free CFrame client area? I need to find some CRect with value (CFrameClientRect without size of docked bars).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From seeing your snapshot I conclude you are using some windows displaying image.

Get this windows rectangle: call `GetWindowRectangle(ptrToRect)`

and convert it to frame window’s client coordinates, passing `rect` as follows:

`pMyFrame->ScreenToClient(ptrToRect)`

Comment: :) The problem is that I don't know new free client rect (img rect) because my bars is RESIZEble. I use Cristi Posea's bars http://www.datamekanix.com/